# What does it mean for a wing's lift distribution to be elliptical when the planform is not?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

How would you go about finding an equation for the lift coefficient of this wing where the lift distribution is known to be elliptical but the planform is not?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The (local) lift depends on many factors - not only the chord but also the profile, angle of incidence - and even up to the actual local flow. Without knowing the details of the actual wing, the distribution of lift can be hard to calculate.